# Как пофиксить 403 ошибку?

Tags: python, парсер, asyncio, aiohttp

парсил ozon, но не могу спарсить сам товар. Когда перехожу по ссылке, где указан весь json с информацией о товаре, выдаёт 403 ошибку.
Ошибка:

```
<ClientResponse(https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v2?url=/product/bryuki-sportivnye-tvoe-528152222/&layout_container=pdpApparelPage2&layout_page_index=1&sh=nU95iScgGA) [403 Forbidden]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Date': 'Sun, 28 Aug 2022 23:01:17 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'close', 'CF-Chl-Bypass': '1', 'Permissions-Policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=EScdZxjHv6uWyquy2bn641iQAGxJCgCSiONUYvdnKHU-1661727677-0-AQFTzurl/YqecQKNQbZwKlo/5NfbOz8TwCR8NvPZJQZw+bn44uh0OnGHW9oNI/l4R7/VqB5SJUHxxhjX2ZIlxLM=; path=/; expires=Sun, 28-Aug-22 23:31:17 GMT; domain=.ozon.ru; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '7420ab013af57b67-DME', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400')>
```

Работаю через asyncio&aiohttp . Не понимаю, может быть проблема в куки, потому что ошибка с доступом безопасности, не пускает сайт?

Код, который должен забирать json:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


agent = UserAgent()
start_time = time.time()
all_pages_data = list()


async def parse_pages():
    url_cat = 'https://www.ozon.ru/category/bryuki-zhenskie-7512/'
    for page in range(1, 3):
        url = f'https://www.ozon.ru/category/bryuki-zhenskie-7512/?page={page}&tf_state=jPsVVJdnHJw3M8GmM_BEw51V4tlgLHemJ6Xo6-ibTo5R7L37'

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)

        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,1200);')
        page_source = driver.page_source

        all_pages_data.append(page_source)
        driver.quit()

    tasks = []
    for page in range(len(all_pages_data)):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(all_pages_data[page], 'lxml')
        card_links = soup.find_all('a', class_='tile-hover-target ju4')
        for card_link in card_links:
            url = '/'.join(card_link.get('href').split('/')[:3])
            task = asyncio.create_task(check_page(url_cat, url, page))
            tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def check_page(url_cat, url, page):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        url_card_data =f'https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v2?url={url}/&layout_container=pdpApparelPage2&' \
                  f'layout_page_index={page}&sh=nU95iScgGA'
        url_for_data = f'https://www.ozon.ru/{url}'
        # url_card_reviews =
        async with session.get(url_card_data, headers={
            'user-agent': f'{agent.random}'
        }) as resp:
            response = await resp.text()
            print(resp)

def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(parse_pages())
    # asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(check_page(all_pages_data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as F:
        writer = csv.writer(F)
        writer.writerow([
            'url', 'name', 'price', 'link', 'feedbacks', 'rating', 'breadcrumbs'
        ])
    main()

    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'elapsed time: {end_time} seconds')
```

Comment: Предоставьте скрипт, который воспроизводит ошибку.

Comment: клаудфлеер не пускает

Comment: @Александр выложил код

Comment: Скрипт должен быть самостоятельным, что бы люди которые пожелают вам помочь, не тратили время на дописывание кода.

Comment: В скрипте который вы дали, не импорта и вызова функции.

Comment: @Александр извините, дополнил

Comment: Через браузер проверяли? Работает без нареканий?

Comment: Да, через браузер всё работает

Comment: а где авторизация и куки?